# PHP - Mysterious Error in Upload script

Tags: php, linux, upload

i'm trying to upload a file to vshare.io trough their api. They're offering a php script to do so:

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('curl_init')) {
    die('CURL functions are not available. Debian: apt-get install php5-curl');
}

$file_path = ''; // Example: $file_path = '/home/files/file.exe';
$token = ''; // You can get your TOKEN from the following page  http://vshare.io/api.html
$post = array(
    'token'    => $token,
    'filesize' => filesize($file_path),
    'Filedata' => '@' . $file_path
);
// init
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://upload.vshare.io/upload_api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:  "));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output = json_decode($result, TRUE);
if(isset($output['upload'], $output['video'], $output['fileid']) && strlen($output['fileid']) == 7 && $output['upload'] == 1) {
    if($output['video'] == '1') {
        $file_type = 'video';
    } elseif($output['video'] == '0') {
        $file_type = 'file';
    }
    echo 'File Type: ' . $file_type . ' | File Link: http://vshare.io/d/' . $output['fileid'];
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . $output['msg'];
}
?>
```

i inserted my token and the correct filepath in Ubuntu, however when launching the script it will run for about 1 minute and then it will print "Error:" (last line of the script say to do so). No files are uploaded to my account

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons. First is your user-agent, you have not set it. The most site today restricted BOT so you should set it for your CURL:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');`

The second reason is that the CURL process time out so you got nothing nor any message.

Try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
```

Comment: added both to the script , but received same output :(                                                   could it be because of this?                           
$result=curl_exec ($ch);                                                                                       i noticed that there is the curl_close command but the execute is incapsulated in in $result.

Comment: Did you try dump the $result, what you received? NULL message?

Comment: if i do that the script will simply block at all forever (lol). no output at all, i have to quit with CTRL + Z

Comment: it may curl_exec function is disabled in server so check the php error logs  if that helps